# jquery post not working the way i expected with the path

Tags: php, jquery, absolute-path

i have this jquery

```
$('.delete_step').live('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var delete_location = 'http//<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>?route=module/cart/delete_builder_step';
     console.log(delete_location);
     var response = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this step?");
    if(response){
       $.post( delete_location,     { step_id: $(this).attr("rel"), builder_id: "<?php print $builder_id; ?>" },
               function(result) {
                     // window.location.reload();
       });
     }
});
```

and all looks good other then in my console I get this

```
 http//localhost?route=module/cart/delete_builder_step
```

which is right but the post is going here

```
http://localhost/shop_pos/admin/http//localhost?route=module/cart/delete_builder_step
```

is there a way to use jQuery post to not be relative and use the full url i specify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `:` in `http://`.

**The correct version:**

```
var delete_location = 'http://<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]; ?>?route=module/cart/delete_builder_step';
```